# self.client.post not working in a test

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue getting this test to work. Here is the whole file on github https://github.com/cbaldwin20/project_9/blob/master/menu/tests.py. Thanks for any advice.

Here is the test

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
def test_edit_item_view_post(self):
        self.client.post(reverse('mysite:item_edit', args=[self.item.id]), {
            'name': 'Ketchup',
            'description': 'Heinz brand',
            'chef': user,
            'ingredients': ['1']
        })
        item1 = Item.objects.get(id=1)
        self.assertEqual(item1.name, 'Ketchup')
```

Here is the view I am testing

```
def edit_item(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ItemForm(instance=item, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('mysite:item_detail', pk=pk)
    form = ItemForm(instance=item)
    return render(request, 'menu/item_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the form

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        exclude = ('created_date',)
```

This is the model the form uses

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    chef = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    standard = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient')
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why do you say it is "not working"?

Comment: The self.assertEqual is returning False. The previous item.name is different, and it is not changing to 'Ketchup'.

Comment: The actual code works fine, it is the test that is not working.

Comment: You sure if the pk is 1?

Comment: yes, I just checked it. I made a 'self.item' in the setUp and its id equals 1.

Comment: You should probably check the response of the post request. Chances are your form data is not valid.

Comment: @sytech    I tried this and it came back False. `def test_valid_data(self):
        form = ItemForm({
            'name': 'Ketchup',
            'description': 'Heinz brand',
            'chef': user,
            'ingredients': ['1'],
        })
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())`

Comment: Why would it always be 1? Most likely, the db is assigning the next id based on whatever has been created before.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman   the view edits an 'Item' object, so the id of that object would stay the same.

Comment: If you do `self.ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create()` in `setUp`, then the item is created before every test, and each time it will have a different id. You should use `self.ingredient.pk` instead of hardcoding `'1'`.

Comment: @Alasdair   I changed it to `'ingredients': [self.ingredient.pk]` and that did not work.

Comment: But you don't post an id of 1, you post whatever item.id is. That's what you should use in the get.

Comment: @Chris [check the form errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) to determine what the errors you have with the submitted form data.

Comment: @sytech sorry it took so long, I've never done this in the console. It says 'chef' is the problem. {'chef': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}

Comment: Try using `user.pk` instead of `user`. Otherwise, it's probably serializing the data in some unknown way. Your form is probably expecting to see the primary key of the choice. Look at the `value` attribute of the select`option` in the HTML; that's what should be sent.

Comment: @sytech   but I print out 'user' and it does exist <User: laceywill>

Comment: @sytech    when I added the pk, 'user.pk' the console said I had no errors, but then I run the test and its still failing.  self.assertEqual(item1.name, 'Ketchup')
AssertionError: 'LKJklsjd' != 'Ketchup'

Comment: @sytech  this is what it says in the html <option value="1" selected="selected">laceywill</option>

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure there are no other errors and `form.is_valid()` is `True`? There may be errors occurring when trying to save the form, since it includes a m2m field. Make sure the supplied 'ingredients' actually exists.

Comment: @sytech   the form is valid when I do it in the terminal with the existing database, but not true in my test file. I will keep working on it.

Comment: You probably neglected to create an ingredient in the test setUp. Therefore (my hunch is) no ingredient with id `1` exists, causing the error, even though the form technically validates. Good luck.

Comment: @sytech      I just checked the ingredient and its there, so I don't know I think its just doomed.

Comment: So if the form is not valid in the unit test, what are the form errors?